# cron schedule for aws trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I am attempting to schedule a trigger on aws, which runs a lambda function daily at 12 noon. My cron expression is `cron(0 0 12 * * ?)` but the aws throws following error:

```
An error occurred when creating the trigger: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException
```

What should be the valid expression?

Comment: Is it from cloudformation?

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression to run CloudWatch event rule daily at 12 is:

```
0 12 1/1 * ? *
```

[image]